# How to save Sqlite Data in Pdf format

Tags: android, sqlite, pdf-generation

I have some set of sqlite data,i.e i have one table,and this table i am displying in      one activity.This record I have to save in pdf format and email to another person.If any one know to save data in pdf fromat so that I can  mail this pdf to whome whatever I want, then please suggest me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with This code By passing your Database value from your table which you want to generate PDF. Here am passing some String values like Paragraph you can change it According your Requirements

```
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                createPDF();

            }
        });

    }


    public void createPDF()
    {
        Document doc = new Document();


         try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";

                File dir = new File(path);
                    if(!dir.exists())
                        dir.mkdirs();

                Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);


                File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

                //open the document
                doc.open();


                Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am generating my first PDF using DroidText");
                Font paraFont= new Font(Font.COURIER);
                p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                p1.setFont(paraFont);

                 //add paragraph to document    
                 doc.add(p1);

                 Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("This is an example of a simple paragraph");
                 Font paraFont2= new Font(Font.COURIER,14.0f,Color.GREEN);
                 p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                 p2.setFont(paraFont2);

                 doc.add(p2);

                 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.android);
                 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
                 Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                 myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                 //add image to document
                 doc.add(myImg);

                 //set footer
                 Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
                 HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
                 doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);



         } catch (DocumentException de) {
                 Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
         } 
         finally
         {
                 doc.close();
         }

    }      
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Generate PDF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will Generate the PDF file this one you can attache and mail

For sending mail you can try this code :

```
String[] mailto = {"me@gmail.com"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("PATH WHERE THE PDF FILE YOU GENERATED");

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Body");
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
```

Comment: first of all thanks to you..for this is there is any rquirement of adding jar file..and which please tell me

Comment: In order to generate PDF use an external library called Droidtext which is used for PDF creation.

Comment: this link may help you for creating pdf with jar  https://github.com/karanbalkar/AndroidPDFDemo

Comment: below mention errors generate after excuting my application     Unable to execute dex: Literal out of range: 000000000000ffff
[2013-12-05 23:19:33 - ProjectPdf] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Literal out of range: 000000000000ffff

Comment: clean the project or restart the eclipse just try once bro

Answer (score 1):

Look at [droidtext](http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/) which a port of the iText library version 2.1.7 for Android.

There are lots of examples too. Get started with [Helloworld](http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/source/browse/trunk/droidTextTest/src/examples/com/lowagie/examples/general/HelloWorld.java).

```
public class HelloWorld {

        /**
         * Generates a PDF file with the text 'Hello World'
         * 
         * @param args
         *            no arguments needed here
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("Hello World");

                // step 1: creation of a document-object
                Document document = new Document();
                try {
                        // step 2:
                        // we create a writer that listens to the document
                        // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
                        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator + "droidtext" + java.io.File.separator + "HelloWorld.pdf"));

                        // step 3: we open the document
                        document.open();
                        // step 4: we add a paragraph to the document
                        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
                } catch (DocumentException de) {
                        System.err.println(de.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
                }

                // step 5: we close the document
                document.close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iText For android it is pretty simple and easy to use and there are many tutorials available for this. like this one http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iText android` library .which is i think is the best one which provides facility for writing pdf file in android programetically.

First you have to fetch your all data which is there in `SQLite` in Some `ArrayList` or `Model` class.

After that you need to write that data in `iText Library`.

With the usage of `iText Library` ,You can do lots of stuff like to `Bold`, `Italic` or `Underline` fonts of pdf. You can do almost all the task which we require to do in pdf file.

Here [RoseIndia.Net](http://www.roseindia.net/jaVA/itext/index.shtml) Is providing best examples for who doesn't know what is `iText`

Good luck with that